# How to COPY a content of a file and use it as environment variable in DOCKER?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, devops

I'm trying to perform automation process using docker.
I have couple of files in my local system and these files will be used inside of a container, so my code so far looks like the following :

```
FROM docker_image_on_the_internet:stable    
COPY . /root/     

# Now I have a command that will execute the copied files

CMD cmd1 --opt-dir --file-copied

# After executing cmd1, a file will be generated inside of the container, the file name consists of timestamp and a public key, example : UTC--2022-03-07T10-53-08.532008168Z--84e9ed8d078f2bdc71e4ca9a322d2f4222c9b7b7

# Now I have another command that will be executed USING THE FILENAME CREATED

CMD cmd2 --opt-dir --file-created-inside-the-container
```

Is there any way to get the created file from the container and use it directly in cmd2 line? because this file is a JSON file that looks like this :

> File name : UTC--2022-03-07T10-53-08.532008168Z--84e9ed8d078f2bdc71e4ca9a322d2f4222c9b7b7

File content :

```
{"address":"84e9ed8d078f2bdc71e4ca9a322d2f4222c9b7b7","crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","ciphertext":"a14e5429363ce09903aeccf1afa9ea49a02a4974e0fa032d14f7077ceae21588","cipherparams":{"iv":"a214bcb73a74554bb9be59df158c4d4e"},"kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"n":262144,"p":1,"r":8,"salt":"d933d92a667eec528299c354e1efe0da730cea2a53a082dbeafc9ed70ca40a71"},"mac":"803325a434a6541c5d93d15f11762d2907e1da1c6520fc33632934565822733d"},"id":"694ca50f-3ae9-4520-94f9-a80003c3f95f","version":3}
```

Because I need the address public key to be executed as an option in the CMD2, and my local files already contains a .ENV file which supposedly contains that variable (need to copy the address and added to the .env file - or execute it directly in the cmd2 as a string option without using environment variables)

Is there anyway I can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: did you try using `ARG` command ? something like `ARG MY_FILE_PATH=/path/to/my_path` ?

Comment: to pass the argument value, I need the public key inside the contianer, how can i grap that and use it in the next CMD ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create the file elsewhere select him using UTC--* (since this would be the only matching file), move him to the correct destination if you want at the end of the process.

By using `jq` you could extract this variable: `ADDRESS=$(cat <your_file> | jq -r .address)` and then use it.